# How does the shooting method work if $x(t_0)$ and $\dot{x}(t_1)$ are given?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

we're supposed to write a script that solves the ODE $\ddot{x}(t) = a_1x(t)+a_2\dot{x}(t)$ with a given interval $[t_0,t_1]$ and initial values $x(t_0)$ and $\dot{x}(t_1)$ using Newton's method and Runge-Kutta. I've understood how the shooting method can be used to approximate the solution for given $x(t_0)$ and $x(t_1)$, but I'm stuck trying to find out how we can go on about this type of problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you use Runge-Kutta you translate your second order OSE into a first order system. So you just have a condition on the second component of the solution, that you can solve as you would for the first component.

Comment: How or why do you use the Newton method with a linear problem? The linearization of the equation is the equation itself, so you can also just solve the linear equation after determining its coefficients from a sufficient number of function values.